# How to put a log in username and password script inside a csh script?

Tags: linux, unix

How to put a log in username and password script inside a csh script?

I have a script that collects data and dumps it on a file

The problem is: I need to first log-in as su before I could successfully execute the script..
What if I need to call it through a crontab?

I wanted to atleast include in my csh script something that would log-in as SU with password.

Could you guys help me here? I was wasting a lot of time searching but still cant find it... Thanks in advance.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach i (./MACHINE/logs/*/*machinedump010113.log.gz)
zcat $i | sed 's,^,'$i' ,' | awk '{gsub("_"," ",$2)}1' | awk  '{gsub("./dummy/", "");print}' | awk '{gsub("/MACHINE_TS.log.gz_", " ");print}' | awk '{gsub(",", "/");print}' |  awk '{gsub("/", "");print}' | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; } {print $1", "$2", "$3", "$4", "$6", "$7", " substr($0, index($0,$8))}' | awk  '{gsub(".TESTLOG", "");print}'  >> /DUMP/TEST.csv
end

exit
```

Comment: All you need to do is add the script to crontab as root. cron will run the job with root permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sudo for this. Add something like this to your /etc/sudoers

youruser ALL = (root) NOPASSWORD: /path/to/yourscript.csh

Then call the script via cron or by hand like this:

sudo /path/to/yourscript.csh

And it should be executed as root without the need for a password.